# Python+django # from .forms import TaskForm (ввод в бд знач и вывод)

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, sqlite, task

Хочу сделать запись в бд через сайт, и вывод на него же...
Повторяю все по уроку https://youtu.be/6K83dgjkQNw?t=4016
Падает сайт на Django после следующих строк...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\core\checks\registry.py", line 70, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\core\checks\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\core\checks\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\urls\resolvers.py", line 589, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\utils\functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\urls\resolvers.py", line 582, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_modu
le
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\Desktop\123\taskmanager\taskmanager\urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('', include('main.urls'))
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\djang
o\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_modu
le
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\Desktop\123\taskmanager\main\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\Desktop\123\taskmanager\main\views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .forms import TaskForm
  File "C:\Users\lagonewsfm\Desktop\123\taskmanager\main\forms.py", line 12
    'placeholder': 'введите название'
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

views.py

```
from .forms import TaskForm

def create(request):
     error = ''
     if request.method == 'POST'
         form = TaskForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             form.save()
             return redirect('sanya')
         else:
             error = 'Форма была не верна'



     form = TaskForm()
     context = {
         'form': form
     }
     return render(request, 'main/create.html',context)
```

forms.py

```
from .models import Task
from django.forms import ModelForm, TextInput, Textarea


class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ["title", "task"]
        widgets = {
              "title": TextInput(attrs= {
              'class': 'form-control'
              'placeholder': 'введите название'
        }),
              "task": Textarea(attrs={
              'class': 'form-control'
              'placeholder': 'введите описание'
        }),
        }
```

! https://ibb.co/bQcj9pK ! - сам HTML и кнопки
! https://ibb.co/7KcRs5F ! -Pycharm скрин

Comment: во вьшке return не полный добавили. И код ошибки добавьте в вопрос

Comment: Исправил :):):)

Comment: ошибка связана с отступами. Скиньте полный код ошибки. также советую поставить pycharm или что-то в этом роде. Чтобы ide сразу показывала где допущены ошибки.

Comment: Добавил лог и скрин пайчарма)

Comment: @AleksandrKasyuk Что там выше TaskForm? Похоже кавычка или скобка не закрыта. в ошибке `render` не закрыт и `context` не передан в файле `views`.

Comment: проблема в `return` 30 строчка. Если пока не передаете `context` оставьте так `return render(request, 'main/create.html',{})`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin контекст уже передается, там в скине есть html - может в нём ошибка?

Comment: @Sherlock `render` закрыт, сайт сразу не работает после импорта TaskForm- может здесь что-то ...

Comment: из кода что вы исправили в вопросе вижу что не хватает пробела перед `return`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin добавил пробел и ошибка изменилась

Comment: в файле с фомрой вообще беда с отступами) судя из того что вставлено в вопрос

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin поправил и ошибка снова изменилась)))

Comment: запятые после  `'class': 'form-control'` в 2ух виджетах

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin УРА все заработало!!!

Comment: вообще такие ошибки ide pycharm должен подчеркивать и писать в чем проблема.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Не хватало запятых при описании widgets